# using FieldValue in fireabase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Does admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) implement atomically meaning that I can use it instead of using transactions (say for increasing the likes count)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` instead of a Transaction.

It is actually mentioned in the documentation of Transactions, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#node.js_1) and below where I pasted the content of the doc (see the following comment in the code: "Note: this could be done without a transaction by updating the population using `FieldValue.increment()`")

```
// Initialize document
let cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');
let setCity = cityRef.set({
  name: 'San Francisco',
  state: 'CA',
  country: 'USA',
  capital: false,
  population: 860000
});

let transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
  return t.get(cityRef)
    .then(doc => {
      // Add one person to the city population.
      // Note: this could be done without a transaction
      //       by updating the population using FieldValue.increment()
      let newPopulation = doc.data().population + 1;
      t.update(cityRef, {population: newPopulation});
    });
}).then(result => {
  console.log('Transaction success!');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
});
```